# Why can't I set a breakpoint in ruby-debug?

Tags: ruby, jruby, breakpoints, ruby-debug

When I try to set a breakpoint from the command-line ruby debugger "ruby-debug," I get the following error:

```
(rdb:1) break 11
INTERNAL ERROR!!! undefined method `entries' for #<String:0x2f3cf887>
```

I'm using JRuby version 1.7.3.
I'm using ruby-debug version 0.10.4.

Answer (score 1):

According to this forum, it's a known bug in ruby-debug: [http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3636709](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3636709#1058565)

A patch is also mentioned on that forum. I'll repeat it for completeness.

Change line 8 of `$GEM_HOME/gems/ruby-debug-base-0.10.4-java/lib/linecache-ruby.rb` from

```
(1..code.entries.size).to_a
```

to

```
(1..code.lines.count).to_a
```

That fixed it for me.