# Why can't I set a breakpoint in ruby-debug with jruby

Tags: jruby, rubymine, ruby-debug

I trying to set breakpoint in ruby-debug when run on jruby.
first I get error some like in this post [Why can't I set a breakpoint in ruby-debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747159/why-cant-i-set-a-breakpoint-in-ruby-debug)

I patched linecache like Mashmagar say. First error disappear. And now I get another error

```
21582: Exception in DebugThread loop: undefined method `errmsg' for #<Debugger::ControlState:0x638bbdc5>
Backtrace:
/home/darius/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/gems/ruby-debug-0.10.4/cli/ruby-debug/command.rb:188:in `errmsg'
  from: /home/darius/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/gems/ruby-debug-0.10.4/cli/ruby-debug/commands/breakpoints.rb:81:in `execute'
  from: /home/darius/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta17/lib/ruby-debug-ide/ide_processor.rb:89:in `process_commands'
  from: org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1254:in `catch'
  from: /home/darius/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta17/lib/ruby-debug-ide/ide_processor.rb:86:in `process_commands'
  from: /home/darius/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta17/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:122:in `start_control'
  from: org/jruby/RubyProc.java:274:in `call'
  from: org/jruby/RubyProc.java:215:in `call'
[2013-07-04 19:18:08] ERROR SystemExit: exit
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:866:in `exit'
```

I use jruby-1.7.4
and ruby-debug-0.10.4 gem